# Selecting the array to become object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I was given an array and an object, and I am creating a function that returns a new object whose properties are those in the given object AND whose keys are present in the given array. If keys are present in the given array, but are not in the given object, it should ignore them. It does not modify the passed in object.

So far I got this:

```
function select(arr, obj) {
  var myObj = {};

  for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = obj[];
  }

}

var arr = ['a', 'c', 'e'];
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};
var output = select(arr, obj);
console.log(output); // --> IT MUST RETURN { a: 1, c: 3 }
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Two things: 1. You don't perform a lookup in the object. 2. You don't actually return anything.

Answer (score 1):

You had it, nearly,

- if you add a check if the key is in the object ([`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)) and then
- you need an assignment to the new property of the return object and at least,
- you need to return that object.

```js
function select(arr, obj) {
    var myObj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] in obj) {
            myObj[arr[i]] = obj[arr[i]];
        }
    }
    return myObj;
}

var arr = ['a', 'c', 'e'],
    obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 },
    output = select(arr, obj);

console.log(output); // { a: 1, c: 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's ES6 one liner ;)

```js
var arr = ['a', 'c', 'e'];
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};

var r = Object.keys(obj).reduce((o, v) => {return (arr.some(a => {return a===v;}) && (o[v] = obj[v]), o)}, {});

console.log(r);
```